# post rating system function

Tags: php, wordpress, post, rating

There's code below for simple post rating system (tutorial from this site [TUTORIAL](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-post-rating-system-with-wordpress-and-jquery/) ) - it works fine but i need to change it a bit. Now where user votes, he is not able to vote again for same post for $timebeforevote (1440 minutes). I want to block user voting for all post not just for this one.

I think the problem is function is looking for user ip in current post meta field with this code:

```
$meta_IP = get_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP");
$voted_IP = $meta_IP[0];
```

Returns `$voted_IP` and compares it with `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` I tried to modify it with query (where query looks for ip in meta field for all posts) so it would search for ip in all posts but it didn't work. I am trying to make it work for 2 days and nothing works.

POST RATING SYSTEM CODE:

```
$timebeforerevote = 1440;

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post-like', 'post_like');
add_action('wp_ajax_post-like', 'post_like');

wp_enqueue_script('like_post', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/post-like.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', 1 );
wp_localize_script('like_post', 'ajax_var', array(
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')
));

function post_like()
{
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ajax-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');

    if(isset($_POST['post_like']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

        $meta_IP = get_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP");

        $voted_IP = $meta_IP[0];
        if(!is_array($voted_IP))
            $voted_IP = array();

        $meta_count = get_post_meta($post_id, "votes_count", true);

        if(!hasAlreadyVoted($post_id))
        {
            $voted_IP[$ip] = time();

            update_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP", $voted_IP);
            update_post_meta($post_id, "votes_count", ++$meta_count);

            echo $meta_count;
        }
        else
            echo "already";
    }
    exit;
}

function hasAlreadyVoted($post_id)
{
    global $timebeforerevote;

    $meta_IP = get_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP");
    $voted_IP = $meta_IP[0];
    if(!is_array($voted_IP))
        $voted_IP = array();
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(in_array($ip, array_keys($voted_IP)))
    {
        $time = $voted_IP[$ip];
        $now = time();

        if(round(($now - $time) / 60) > $timebeforerevote)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function getPostLikeLink($post_id)
{
    $themename = "twentyeleven";

    $vote_count = get_post_meta($post_id, "votes_count", true);

    $output = '<p class="post-like">';

    if ($vote_count == 0)
        $output .= '<span class="count">0<span class="glosow"><br>głosów w rankingu</span></span>';
    else
        $output .= '<span class="count">'.$vote_count.'<span class="glosow"><br>głosów w rankingu</span></span>';

    if(hasAlreadyVoted($post_id))
        $output .= '<span title="Już głosowałeś" class="qtip alreadyvoted"></span>';
    else
        $output .= '<a href="#" data-post_id="'.$post_id.'">
                    <span  title="'.__('Głosuj', $themename).'"class="qtip like"></span></a>';
    $output .= '</p>';

    return $output;
}
```

Heres code for query that finds if user already voted but problem is that after $timebeforerevote IP value stays in meta field so i can't use it. I have no more ideas for now...

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'meta_key' => 'voted_IP', 
    'meta_value' => $ip
) );
if (0 !== $query->found_posts) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: _"I tried to modify it with query (where query looks for ip in meta field for all posts) "_ This would be in the right direction. Where's the code for that?

Comment: Added to main question in 'do something part' i wanted display vote section if only if query doesnt find user ip adress in meta field 'voted_IP' but I realized that meta field isn't cleared after $timebeforerevote time so i could not use it.

Comment: $voted_IP[$ip] = time(); update_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP", $voted_IP); I think in this line. But I cant understand how ip is stored as time.

Comment: Dont know - i followed tutorial and it worked but after voting only voted post is blocked for voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
        $voted_IP[$ip] = time();

        update_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP", $voted_IP);
        update_post_meta($post_id, "votes_count", ++$meta_count);
```

...indicates that the voting attempts are stored in the post's `voted_IP` meta, in the form of an `ip=>timestamp` array. That makes `'meta_value' => $ip` in your query *invalid*, because you are trying to match a string with an array. Instead, just query for all posts that have this meta key and then do some iterations:

```
global $post;
$tmp=$post;
$recently_voted=false;
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'meta_key' => 'voted_IP', 
//    'meta_value' => $ip // invalid...
) );
if (0 !== $query->found_posts) {
  $now=time();
  while($query->have_posts())
    {
    $id=$post->id;
    $meta_IP=get_post_meta($id,"voted_IP"); // this is an array
    if(isset($meta_IP[$ip])&&($now-$meta_IP[$ip]<1440*60))
      {
      $recently_voted=true; // found at least one recent vote
      break;
      }
    }
}
$post=$tmp;
```